# How to Pass points to cvFitEllipse2 in OpenCV

Tags: c++, iphone, opencv

I am new to OpenCV, I have array of CGPoints and I need to pass those values to cvFitEllipse2, how to pass those values? Right now I am getting exception if I pass like below

```
    std::vector<cv::Point> contours;
    contours.resize(self.points.count);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < self.points.count ; i++)
    {
        CGPoint point = [self.points objectAtIndex:i];
        cv::Point val;
        val.x = point.x;
        val.y = point.y;
        contours[i] = val;
    }

    CvBox2D rect = cvFitEllipse2(&contours);
```

Comment: please use cv::fitEllipse, not the arcane c-api calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> contours;
contours.resize(self.points.count);
for(int i = 0 ; i < self.points.count ; i++)
{
    CGPoint point = [self.points objectAtIndex:i];
    cv::Point val;
    val.x = point.x;
    val.y = point.y;
    contours[i] = val;
}

cv::RotatedRect rect = cv::fitEllipse(contours);
```

afterwards you can convert the rotatedRect to the type you need.

If you want to use the C API for the fitEllipse call, you have to convert your vector to either `CvSeq*` or `CvMat*` according to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitellipse#fitellipse